# Можно ли узнать сколько выделено памяти в куче на указателе?

Tags: c++

Проблема, про которую хорошо описана в коде.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void example_func(int*& b)
{
    //Допустим мне надо пройтись по всему массиву (ну отсортировать допустим)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < /* размер массива. */; i++) //что то наподобие b.size() или sizeof(b)/sizeof(int)? 
    {
        /*
            ...
        */
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    example_func(a);
}
```

Конечно как решение можно в аргументы функции передавать еще и размер массива, но хочется сделать все более кратко.

Comment: Нельзя, освобождайте память после `new[]`.

Comment: По указателю - нет.

Comment: *"можно в аргументы функции передавать еще и размер массива"* - не только можно, но и нужно, а еще лучше использовать `std::span`

Comment: А почему не использовать std::vector - он как раз для этого и предназначен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нельзя узнать.
2. Не забывайте освобождать выделенную память после `new[]`.
3. Чтобы явно не передавать размер, можно сделать [так](https://godbolt.org/z/E4k9PQ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
using namespace std;

void example_func(span<int> b)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
        b[i] = 42;
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    example_func({a, n});
    delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: Только дописали бы, что это - C++20.

Comment: @Mikhailo да, это так

Comment: Просто мне кажется, что сейчас еще мало кто знаком с ним, и не у всех компиляторы с его поддержкой, так что, как три года назад с С++17, сейчас лучше явно указывать в ответе, что используется С++20.

Answer (score 1):

Можно не передавать аргументом характеристики массива, а только его адрес. Создаёте структуру с характеристиками и сами данные. `new` и `delete` для нового массива использовать нельзя. Всё только рукоделием `New` и `Del`.

```
// g++-9 -Wall -Os arrsize.cpp
# include <cstddef>
# include <cstdlib>

template<class T>
class Array {
public :
  operator  T * ( void ) { return p ; }
  operator  T const * ( void )  const { return p ; }
  size_t  size  ( ) const { return  n ; }
  static  Array & New ( size_t ) ;
  void  Del ( ) ;
private :
  size_t  n ;
  T p [ ] ;
} ;

template<class T>
Array<T> & Array<T> :: New ( size_t const  s ) {
  Array < T > & a = * (Array < T > *)
    malloc  ( sizeof(Array<T>)+sizeof(T[s]) ) ;
  for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < s ; ++ i )
    new ( & ( a . p [ i ] ) ) T ;
  a . n = s ;
  return  a ; }
  
template<class T>
void  Array<T> :: Del ( ) {
  for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; ++ i )
    ( p [ i ] ) . ~ T ( ) ;
  free ( this ) ; }

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void example_func(Array < int > & b)
{
    //Допустим мне надо пройтись по всему массиву (ну отсортировать допустим)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    {
      b[i] = i ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    Array<int> & a = Array < int > :: New (n);
    example_func(a);
    cout << "a["<<n/2<<"]="<<a[n/2]<<std::endl;
    ++(a[n/2]);
    Array<int> const & b = a ;
    cout << "b["<<n/2<<"]="<<b[n/2]<<std::endl;
    a.Del();
}
```

Фактически это массив, но с дополнительной информацией. На любителя.

Comment: Тогда уж проще использовать `std::array`.

Comment: Я хотел предложить `array`, но эта зараза шаблон от фиксированного размера. Пришлось передумать. @Mikhailo

Comment: @Mikhailo скорее вектор

Comment: @AlexGlebe а чего у вас такое форматирование странное?) То пробелы, то без пробелов, сложно читать, если честно